# Changing color of words in sentence that match the words in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, colors

Trying to figure out how to code this - hopefully someone can help out!

I'm making a simple project that allows the user to change the color of specific words by clicking a button.

For example this is the sentence:

```
<p>i cant believe mary tried to kill her own sister, bella ! </p>
```

and the words I want to change color are "mary", "kill", "bella"

I know I need to have an array of the words I want to change but I don't sure how to assign/connect the sentence with the array.

I already coded a button that changes the color of the whole sentence* but can't figure how to get the array elements connected - does anyone know how to? Thanks!

*code

```
 <p>i cant believe mary tried to kill her own sister, bella !</p> 
 <br/>

 <input id="changeColor" type="button" value="Change Color" />

//JQUERY CHANGES TEXT TO BLUE WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED
$(function() {
    $('#changeColor').click( function() {
        $("p").css({"color":"blue"});
    });
});
```

> **EDIT :** reviewed the comments you guys left - sorry for leaving out vital information! Thank you for the feedback as well!

Comment: You can mention somethin like this. <p> i cant believe <span class="your css">mary</span> tried to kill her own sister, <span class="your css">bella</span>!</p>

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried so far? As for linking words to colors, you might consider creating an object whose keys are the words you want to change and the value is the color.

Comment: *I already coded a button that changes the color* - at least, you could show that code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const words = ['mary', 'kill', 'bella']

const p = document.querySelector('p')
var newHTML = p.innerHTML
words.forEach(word=>
  newHTML = newHTML.replace(word, `<span class="color">${word}</span>`)
)
p.innerHTML = newHTML
```

```css
.color {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>i cant believe mary tried to kill her own sister, bella ! </p>
```

First, put the words of which you want to change color in an array. Then select the `<p>` element using `document.querySelector()`. Assign the current HTML content of that element to a variable, and for each word in the array, replace that world with a `<span>` with a class `color`, which contains that word. Then assign the changed HTML to `innerHTML` property of the `<p>` element.

You also have to set the color you want in CSS.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you for helping out and navigating through that mess of a question!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just making a "simple project that allows the user to change the color of specific words by clicking a button", then you can do it by just adding a `<span>` tag to each of the words and change them in javascript by targeting each id like below. You say "I know I need to have an array" but I can't tell if you mean that like you think you can only do this with an array or if you WANT to do this with an array. To me, it sounds like the former, so below is without the use of an array and span tags. If you NEED to do this with an array, it can be done in a very similar way but it's not really necessary if you want 3 separate buttons.

```js
function changeRed() {
 document.getElementById('red').style.color = 'red';
  }

function changeBlue() {
 document.getElementById('blue').style.color = 'blue';
  }

function changeGreen() {
 document.getElementById('green').style.color = 'green';
  }
```

```html
<p>i cant believe <span id="red">mary</span> tried to <span id="blue">kill</span> her own sister, <span id="green">bella</span> ! </p>

<button type="button" onclick="changeRed()">mary</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeBlue()">kill</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeGreen()">bella</button>
```

Comment: Hi JoeL! Excuse the ambiguity in my question - I wasn't exactly sure how to articulate what I wanted to ask. (Still don't) but I wanted to verbalize that I was trying to change the color of certain words that were **both** in a sentence and in an array. Gothdo's answer sorta of clarifies what I was going for but your response was great and helpful. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You could just put `span` tags around the words and give it an `id=mary`, `id=kill`etc.

If you want all of those words to change to the same color, just give each `span` the same class name.

Can you include the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 0):

I explained it in the code comments below.

HTML:

```
<div id="sentenceContainer">Placeholder</div>
<button id="changeButton">Change</button>
<button id="resetButton">Reset</button>
```

CSS:

```
#sentenceContainer {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#sentenceContainer > span:not(:first-child) {
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// We make an array of the words
var words = ["i", "cant", "believe", "mary", "tried", "to", "kill", "her", "own", "sister,", "bella", "!"];

// These are the indices from the array above that correspond to the words you want to turn red
var redIndices = [3, 6, 10];

$('#changeButton,#resetButton').on('click', writeWords);

// This is the function that will write the sentence for us
function writeWords(evt) {

  // Get the ID of the target to know if we are changing or resetting
  var red = evt && evt.target && $(evt.target).attr('id') === 'changeButton' ? true : false;

  // This grabs our sentenceContainer
  // Always grab these outside of any loops to speed up code execution
  // Otherwise there would be a DOM traversal for each iteration of the loop
  var sentenceContainer = $('#sentenceContainer');

  // Empty it so it doesn't repeat the sentence
  sentenceContainer.empty();

  // Iterate the words array
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    // Generate the container
    var wordSpan = $('<span></span>');

    // Add the word to it
    wordSpan.text(words[i]);

    // If this is a word we want red, from redIndices - we add the class red
    if (red && redIndices.indexOf(i) >= 0)
      wordSpan.addClass('red');

    // Append the word container to the sentence container
    sentenceContainer.append(wordSpan);
  }

};

writeWords();
```

View this live:

http://codepen.io/noahtkeller/pen/QEOOyL